# Is this Poe Damerons dad, Kes Dameron?

Tags: star-wars, the-empire-strikes-back

Is this person circled in the image Kes Dameron, Poe Dameron's father?

[image: Rebellion troops in the trenches at Hoth waiting for the Empire's attack. They are leaning against the walls and sat down in their own thoughts wearing the Rebel's snow camouflage. The one in the foreground leaning against the trench wall is circled]

Comment: Do you have any reason for thinking he is?

Comment: No mate, that's Jeff. Jeff Starspanker. Lovely bloke.

Comment: ...works in accounts?

Answer (score 5):

That's probably not [Kes Dameron](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Kes_Dameron) - at least, not in canon, yet...

Kes Dameron (who is Poe's father) first appears in the canon comic books *Shattered Empire* during the Battle of Endor.

It is possible he was on Hoth with the Rebels, but there doesn't seem to be anything to support that, yet

Answer (score 1):

I doubt it and also, if (I don't know where he got it from but IF) Poe inherited his flying skills from his father then why isn't he in the sky destroying the AT-AT's?

Comment: http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Kes_Dameron - Poe's father was a rebel commando Sergeant, and his mother was rebel pilot... but flying skill isn't necessarily heritable

Answer (score 0):

Actually...
The latest Star Wars comics confirm that Kes and Shara were at Hoth, even built some of the tunnels. Shara was the pilot who taught Poe at six years old. Kes was a Pathfinder, better with a blaster than an A-Wing so this could be a plausible appearance and Pablo Hidalgo should be asked if you can find someone on his Twitter.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Can you provide a specific reference (comic name and issue #) and an exact quote?  That would make this a better answer, though it wouldn't really address if this _specific_ trooper is Kes.

Comment: @Erica Dawn - An anonymous user, who may in fact be you, has attempted to edit this answer to add a source. If it is you, please use your original account to edit the answer, so we know that it's actually you. Or if you can't access that account for some reason, then please follow the instructions provided at [this link](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) so you can merge your new account with the old one, and regain the ability to edit this answer yourself.